# MVC5 Object reference not set to an instance of an object on Scripts.Render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Asp.net MVC5 and haven't encountered such this ambiguous error since 4 years working with Microsoft MVC platform! The error occurs in *Manage* page in default MVC5 template. here **in line 26** at the `_layout.cshtml` file:

```
Line 24:     <![endif]-->
Line 25: 
Line 26:     @Scripts.Render("~/js/intf")
Line 27:     <script>
Line 28:         if (document.documentMode === 10) {
```

The Stack Trace says:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\Users\fake\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\name\name\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:26
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
>   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6(TextWriter
>   writer) +232    System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter
>   writer) +10    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult
>   result) +80
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String
>   partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +267
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +291    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__19()
>   +173    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9688704    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

**Edit**:
As you wanted the bundling code, I placed one of them here:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/intf").Include(//first internal scripts
                "~/js/jquery*",
                "~/js/modernizr.js",
                "~/js/ie-prototype-polyfill.js",
                "~/js/prettyPhoto.js"));
```

**NOTE**: If I commentize the error lines (style/script bundling lines) The error will be `@ViewBag.Title` as the new error! I think the Razor view Engine got into trouble here, since it can't instantiate the view's codes requirements, But Why??

I know that some errors in working with Microsoft technologies aren't really related to the error that it says. Please left me your beneficial experiences. Thanks.

**Update**:
The terse contents for `~/views/Account/Manage.cshtml` file maybe useful:

```
@using Social.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "manage";
}

<div class="layout-app">

    <div class="row row-app margin-none">

        <div class="col-md-12">

            @if (ViewBag.HasLocalPassword)
            {
                 @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial")
            }
            else
            {
                 @Html.Partial("_SetPasswordPartial")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have all related bundling codes which are working on other pages fine. what happened?

Comment: Please show us the bundle config.

Comment: In your jQuery, please add ".js" to the extension - like `jquery*.js` or `.Include("~/js/jquery-{version}.js")`

Comment: @janhartmann The same error already exists. All the pages work fine except this one. All the pages using the same layout file like one that used here.

Comment: Salam, Do you have `Authorize` attribute on your controller/action?

Comment: It looks like exact error is not on this line can u please check that your implementation of view , controller code , may be error is throwing from there.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy Indeed, It used before Controller class, So needs to be authorized, The user Accessing this page is authorized too.

Comment: Can u please provide your view , controller code so we can try to find problem.

Comment: @JineshJain Dear friend, The Controller contents are the same as used in default MVC5 template on creating without any changes. The Manage View is the same as used in default with some changes in `HTML`.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi Try renaming the bundle from `~js/intf` to `~bundles/js/intf`.  Both in the config and in the layout file

Comment: @ColinBacon OK, Do you mean a name conflict occurred with other reserved names likely in Platform?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi Sometimes it believes it to be an actual file path and errors because that file cannot be found.

Comment: If the error happens even when the bundle is commented out then maybe it isn't the bundling that is erroring. Maybe post a bit more of the view or provide a sequence of steps for us to produce with the default project

Comment: @ColinBacon Your last solution didn't work :( , I also tried another names instead of `/intf` but it's not solved!

Comment: @Shoe I just changed some `html` markups in *Manage.cshtml* file but put some of its contents for you maybe useful :)

Comment: Is this reproducible with a brand new project?

Comment: @Shoe It just reproduced lately. The problem will be solved when I set the `Layout=null;` for *manage.cshtml* ! All the pages work fine with the Layout and its bundles! What's your idea? It's So ambiguous

Comment: Maybe post some pieces of your Layout file?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie VS 2013 with MVC5 Internet Application, Froms Authentication

Comment: After too many inspection, I found out missing the enumeration of a required Dynamic data (named `ViewBag.pd`) in the master layout file caused the Error! But why shows me this? At least It must direct me to the line which uses `ViewBag.pd` !!!

Comment: @Shoe I found out the main issue and wrote it as comment, This is the most far away error that I've seen from Microsoft So far! Just as an experience!

Comment: Best way to resolve that is to not use ViewBag :)

Comment: @Shoe You're right :). It seems Dynamic Types like `ViewBag` and `ViewData` can't be tracked or debugged. But how to do with cases we need more than 2 models in each page when working with complex data to be passed into the page?

Comment: Make a viewmodel to hold both models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I misused `ViewBag` in master layout file to consume in other pages. My structure made `ViewBag` as a *required* field so I had to *instantiate* it before. But **I forgot to instantiate it** which caused to fire such this error and it seems to be irrelevant to `Scripts.Render`.

Comment: For me, the @model declaration for the view model was null and that was causing the error. The error really did have nothing to do with the fix. It was telling me that a Styles.Render was a null reference.

Comment: Huh, I'm also getting an "object reference not set" exception on the bottom "@Scripts.Render(...)" call in my shared layout cshtml file, but I can see nothing wrong with anything. It's a super simple test site I'm using to follow along to a tutorial series. Grrrr

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new javascript file in, for example, the folder Scripts in your MVC solution and call the file app.js (or anything else).

Then place the following line underneath the other @scripts.Render lines to run it.

```
<script src="@Scripts.Url("~/Scripts/app.js")"></script>
```

Otherwise add the file to a bundle.