# Strange error with rendering scripts on layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

The last line in the `body` element of my `_Layout.cshtml` is:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Yet when I run my app, I get the exception:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".

Strange enough right, because `Scripts` is not required. Then, in my login page, I comment out the following line:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And the app runs fine. Is this somehow because the `jqueryval` bundle is empty, so the view engine thinks that the `Scripts` section is not being rendered in `_Layout.cshtml`? My `BundleConfig` includes the script in question, and it is present in my `Scripts` folder, so what could be wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Do you happen to have nested layout pages (which could throw that error)

Answer (score 2):

We consider that you know the Section requisites to work fine in MVC template. Such this strange errors occur **when you have another errors** (not really related to `RenderSection`) in page and the framework reflects the wrong error instead of showing the main one. Take a look at [my recent issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492101/mvc5-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-on-scripts-render) which comes from an undefined and used `ViewBag.sth` in the related page. Or another example could be [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1807256.aspx?The%20following%20sections%20have%20been%20defined%20but%20have%20not%20been%20rendered%20for%20the%20layout%20page%20Views%20Shared%20_Layout%20cshtml%20) where the owner encounters error with mobile sometimes! The answer of the last one will be the same, I think the owner uses variables perhaps by the browser help to populate data on page and error occurs when they're not ready before finishing the page rendering. **briefly say**, Such this irrelevant errors occur *when the view variables aren't ready (not enumerated or initialized)* and the debugger shows us an strange error. So, *you've used an unassigned and used variable during the page renders.*

**Solution**: check the used variables (Dynamic variables like `ViewBag` or `ViewData`) in your page, tracking from master layout file to final rendered page (including partial views) to find out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

Also you can wrap the `@RenderSection` in an if block:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("scripts"))
{
    RenderSection("scripts");
}
```

**Update**: Make sure that, the `RenderSection` has the same name with section defined in your views, for example in your _Layout you should have the following `RenderSection`:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

And in other views:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

If the name (in this case `Scripts`) doesn't match, it throws that error:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".

Also, make sure your `_ViewStart.cshtml` points to right layout:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

Comment: The normal `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)` doesn't work, and I'm asking this question to find out why, not how to work around it like your second example. If `Scripts` is optional, the MVC runtime should be doing the `@if (IsSectionDefined("scripts"))`, not me. But thanks, I may use the workaround if I don't come right in time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Layout page is rendering from `_ViewStart` and not referenced directly on your `View`. Please make sure that `_Layout` is referenced on your `View` directly, i.e:

`@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}`

Comment: Why should I have to do that? What is the purpose of `_ViewStart` then?

Comment: `ViewStart` is a special view which derives from `ViewStartPage` instead of `WebViewPage` which other views derive from. And the `ViewStartPage` class doesn't have a `DefineSection` method. So you cannot define sections in this file.

Comment: `RenderSection` can consume only sections defined immediately by the view using them. Since `_ViewStart` runs before any view requested code runs, this is why it is not available there.

This is by design. Currently `Razor` layouts can only consume (render) `sections` defined immediately by the `view` using them. You cannot have a hierarchy of layout pages and in the outermost layout consume a `section` defined in the innermost `view`.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer, because I don't have enough credits to post a comment to your question. Sorry.

But are you sure, your login page refers the same layout page?

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

to this

```
@section Scripts
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jqueryval.js")"></script> 
}
```

If you want to render scripts on a view page you must set

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
```

Comment: Using a `script` tag defeats the purpose of the whole bundling and minifying feature of MVC, and I definitely don't want to move backwards like that. Then, `required: true` defeats the purpose of having *optional* script sections on my views.